# How to change label in gtkada and glade

Tags: ada, settext, glade

I am having a trouble with set_text to change the label when I clicked the button

error:

```
Builder results
    C:\Users\MaxPayne\Desktop\Ada workspace\Gui3\src\window_play.adb
        42:16 expected an access type with designated type "Gtk_Label_Record" defined at gtk-label.ads:189
        42:16 found package or procedure name
```

The error in the line: Set_Text (Label, "The button clicks:" & Natural'Image (Count));

This is the sample code: of simple_glade3.adb

```
with Gtk;            use Gtk;
with Gtk.Main;       use Gtk.Main;
with Gtk.Widget;     use Gtk.Widget;
with Gtkada.Builder; use Gtkada.Builder;

-- the following package is user defined.
with Simple_Callbacks; use Simple_Callbacks;
with Window_Play; use Window_Play;

with Gtk.Builder; use Gtk.Builder;
with Gtk.Window; use Gtk.Window;
with Gtk.Button; use Gtk.Button;
with Gtkada.Handlers;  use Gtkada.Handlers;
use Gtkada.Handlers;

with Glib; use Glib;
with Glib.Error; use Glib.Error;
with Gtk.Main;
with Gtk.Label; use Gtk.Label;
with Gtk.Frame;     use Gtk.Frame;
with ada.Text_IO; use ada.Text_IO;


procedure Simple_Glade3 is

   Builder : Gtkada_Builder;
   error : aliased GError;
   Win   : Gtk_Window;
   ret : GUint;
   Button : Gtk_Button;

begin
   Gtk.Main.Init;

   Gtk_New (Builder);
   ret := Builder.Add_From_File ("welcomemenu.glade", error'Access);

   Register_Handler
     (Builder      => Builder,
      Handler_Name => "Main_Quit", -- from XML file <signal handler=..>
      Handler      => Simple_Callbacks.Quit'Access);

   Do_Connect (Builder);

   button := Gtk_Button (Builder.Get_Object ("btn_play"));
   button.On_Clicked (changeLabel'Access);

   Win := Gtk_Window (Builder.Get_Object ("win_main"));
   Win.Show_All;
   Gtk.Main.Main;

   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("The demo is over");
   Unref (Builder);


end Simple_Glade3;
```

window_play.ads

```
with Gtkada.Builder; use Gtkada.Builder;
with Gtk.Main;
with Gtk.Button; use Gtk.Button;
package Window_Play is

   procedure Quit (Object : access Gtkada_Builder_Record'Class);
   procedure changeLabel (Self : access Gtk_Button_Record'Class);

end Window_Play;
```

window_play.adb

```
with Gtk;            use Gtk;
with Gtk.Main;       use Gtk.Main;
with Glib.Error;     use Glib.Error;
with Gtk.Widget;     use Gtk.Widget;
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Gtkada.Builder; use Gtkada.Builder;

-- the following package is user defined.
with Simple_Callbacks; use Simple_Callbacks;

with Gtk.Builder; use Gtk.Builder;
with Gtk.Window; use Gtk.Window;
with Gtk.Button; use Gtk.Button;
with Gtkada.Handlers;  use Gtkada.Handlers;

with Glib; use Glib;
with Glib.Error; use Glib.Error;
with Gtk.Main;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Gtk.Label; use Gtk.Label;


package body Window_Play is

   Builder : Gtkada_Builder;
   error : aliased GError;
   Win   : Gtk_Window;
   ret : GUint;
   Button : Gtk_Button;
   Count  : Natural := 0;

   procedure Quit (Object : access Gtkada_Builder_Record'Class) is
      pragma Unreferenced (Object);
   begin
      Gtk.Main.Main_Quit;
   end Quit;

   procedure changeLabel (Self : access Gtk_Button_Record'Class) is
   begin
     Count := Count + 1;
     Set_Text (Label, "The button clicks:" & Natural'Image (Count));
   end changeLabel;

end Window_Play;
```

Comment: The error message prefix `42:16` means “line 42, column 16”. The entity at column 16 of that line is `Label`, which doesn’t seem to be declared anywhere; perhaps you meant `Self`?

Comment: I already add Label : Gtk_Label; to declare the label but the error is: 31:4 warning: variable "Label" is read but never assigned

Comment: That’s not an error, it’s a warning. Perhaps you’d better initialize `Label`. But what is the point of `changeLabel`’s  `Self`` parameter? (NB, I don’t use Gtk myself, these are just observations about your code).

Answer (score 1):

As Simon pointed out, the compiler does not see a variable named `Label` at line 42. Instead it sees the package `Gtk.Label` and guesses this is what you are referencing.
Assuming your intent is to change what the button displays,you should simply use

```
Self.Set_Label ("The button clicks:" & Count'Img);
```